# Webbrowser control request headers

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to get the request headers from the webbrowser control after it has connected to a website?

I have had a look around for some code for this, but cannot find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register an Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol handler for your process. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control for an example.